# sorl-thumbnail: Preserve "progressiveness" of JPEG files

Tags: django, image, jpeg, sorl-thumbnail

Most of all JPEG files uploaded to my sites are saved in progressive format, but no thumbnail generated by sorl-thumbnail is generated as progressive when the original image is. This is essential when creating thumbnails of large images, for instance, for display within a carousel/slider.

I have sumbitted [an issue](https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail/issues/55) on sorl's tracker, but I think maybe creating a custom backend based on the existing ones, could solve the issue. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from sorl.thumbnail.engines import pil_engine

class ProgressiveBackend(pil_engine.Engine):
    def _get_raw_data(self, image, format_, quality):
        ImageFile.MAXBLOCK = 1024 * 1024
        buf = StringIO()
        try:
            if format_=='JPEG':
                image.save(buf, format=format_, quality=quality, optimize=1, progressive=image.progressive)
            else:
                image.save(buf, format=format_, quality=quality, optimize=1)
        except IOError:
            image.save(buf, format=format_, quality=quality)
        raw_data = buf.getvalue()
        buf.close()
        return raw_data
```

Comment: I was just testing with a something much like this (mostly copy-paste of that method of the PIL engine). In my version, I wasn't checking if the format is JPEG (it's really necessary?). The real issue was with `image.progressive`. I'm using Python 2.6.7 and PIL 1.1.7, and when trying this answer, the `image` param didn't expose an `progressive` attribute. Then I used `True` and everything worked fine. So what's only left for this answer is how to _detect_ if the original image is a progressive JPEG or not.

Comment: is there any harm in making them all progressive?

Comment: I guess no, just a matter of consistency... Anyway, in that method is troublesome to determine if a JPEG image is progressive or not, so I'm accepting your answer since it's what I'm using right now.